# Flutter Lost connection to device with new USB

Tags: android, visual-studio, android-studio, flutter, adb

So my production Flutter app was working fine but unfortunately, my USB got damaged. So I bought two new USB. But since then, every time in run my project I got the following error:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on RMX1801 in debug mode...
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
√ Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
D/FlutterActivity(32205): Using the launch theme as normal theme.
D/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate(32205): Setting up FlutterEngine.
D/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate(32205): No preferred FlutterEngine was provided. Creating a new FlutterEngine for this FlutterFragment.
W/FlutterEngine(32205): Tried to automatically register plugins with FlutterEngine (io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine@4bc4669) but could not find and invoke the GeneratedPluginRegistrant.
D/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate(32205): Attaching FlutterEngine to the Activity that owns this Fragment.
E/ANR_LOG (32205): >>> msg's executing time is too long
E/ANR_LOG (32205): Blocked msg = { when=-3s964ms what=159 target=android.app.ActivityThread$H obj=android.app.servertransaction.ClientTransaction@3a98be19 } , cost  = 2508 ms
E/ANR_LOG (32205): >>>Current msg List is:
E/ANR_LOG (32205): Current msg <1>  = { when=-3s416ms what=149 target=android.app.ActivityThread$H obj=android.os.BinderProxy@838d0b7 }
E/ANR_LOG (32205): Current msg <2>  = { when=-2s754ms what=131 target=android.app.ActivityThread$H obj=android.app.ActivityThread$ProviderRefCount@bb74efe }
E/ANR_LOG (32205): Current msg <3>  = { when=-2s550ms what=0 target=com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_auth.zzj callback=com.google.firebase.auth.zzm }
E/ANR_LOG (32205): Current msg <4>  = { when=-2s480ms what=0 target=android.app.ActivityThread$H callback=android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection }
E/ANR_LOG (32205): Current msg <5>  = { when=-2s319ms what=0 target=android.app.ActivityThread$H callback=android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection }
E/ANR_LOG (32205): Current msg <6>  = { when=-1s894ms what=1 target=android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler obj=android.os.AsyncTask$AsyncTaskResult@d92365f }
E/ANR_LOG (32205): Current msg <7>  = { when=-340ms what=131 target=android.app.ActivityThread$H obj=android.app.ActivityThread$ProviderRefCount@4c48ac }
E/ANR_LOG (32205): Current msg <8>  = { when=-105ms what=0 target=android.app.ActivityThread$H callback=android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection }
E/ANR_LOG (32205): Current msg <9>  = { when=-97ms what=0 target=android.os.Handler callback=io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate$2 }
E/ANR_LOG (32205): Current msg <10>  = { when=-70ms what=0 target=android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler callback=android.view.ViewRootImpl$4 }
E/ANR_LOG (32205): >>>CURRENT MSG DUMP OVER<<<
D/FlutterView(32205): Attaching to a FlutterEngine: io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine@4bc4669
W/Ads     (32205): Update ad debug logging enablement as false
W/.vedx.mentor10(32205): create CommonDcsHelper
W/.vedx.mentor10(32205): cacheJniMembers success
W/.vedx.mentor10(32205): constructJavaHashMap: start
W/.vedx.mentor10(32205): constructJavaHashMap: end
W/.vedx.mentor10(32205): sendCommonDcs: start
W/.vedx.mentor10(32205): sendCommonDcs: end
W/.vedx.mentor10(32205): Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeInfo;->getSourceNodeId()J (light greylist, reflection)
W/.vedx.mentor10(32205): constructJavaHashMap: start
W/.vedx.mentor10(32205): constructJavaHashMap: end
W/.vedx.mentor10(32205): sendCommonDcs: start
W/.vedx.mentor10(32205): sendCommonDcs: end
W/.vedx.mentor10(32205): Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/accessibility/AccessibilityRecord;->getSourceNodeId()J (light greylist, reflection)
W/.vedx.mentor10(32205): constructJavaHashMap: start
W/.vedx.mentor10(32205): constructJavaHashMap: end
W/.vedx.mentor10(32205): sendCommonDcs: start
W/.vedx.mentor10(32205): sendCommonDcs: end
W/.vedx.mentor10(32205): Accessing hidden field Landroid/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeInfo;->mChildNodeIds:Landroid/util/LongArray; (light greylist, reflection)
W/.vedx.mentor10(32205): constructJavaHashMap: start
W/.vedx.mentor10(32205): constructJavaHashMap: end
W/.vedx.mentor10(32205): sendCommonDcs: start
W/.vedx.mentor10(32205): sendCommonDcs: end
W/.vedx.mentor10(32205): Accessing hidden method Landroid/util/LongArray;->get(I)J (light greylist, reflection)
D/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate(32205): Executing Dart entrypoint: main, and sending initial route: /
I/Choreographer(32205): Skipped 6 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/OpenGLRenderer(32205): Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer(32205): Swap behavior 2
E/Parcel  (32205): Reading a NULL string not supported here.
I/Choreographer(32205): Skipped 24 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
E/Parcel  (32205): Reading a NULL string not supported here.
D/FlutterView(32205): Detaching from a FlutterEngine: io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine@4bc4669
E/Parcel  (32205): Reading a NULL string not supported here.
Lost connection to device.
Exited (sigterm)
```

There is no physical damage in the USB and it does show connected device before the run. But after run both visual studio code and android studio shows Lost connection.

Flutter Doctor:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.9, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.778], locale en-US)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
[√] VS Code (version 1.44.2)
[√] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

I am using windows 10 and Android Device. I want to test and debug my app in real device. Any solution?

Comment: There are a few things that could be happening here, but just to be sure, did you allow USB debugging on your phone?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply debug through usb ..else you can connect your device through LAN..

https://android.jlelse.eu/wireless-debugging-through-adb-in-android-using-wifi-965f7edd163a

Comment: I can't simply debug through USB, because it didn't show my device in the connected device. Please read the question again. Also, I didn't want to use LAN because it's very slow compared to USB.

Answer (score 0):

did you  Try manually uninstall from the phone/simulator and run flutter clean ,
also try once disable automatic opening of dart devtools in chrome

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new default flutter project and debug that into your phone.